# Is storing a username in localstorage bad practice?

Tags: local-storage, jwt

I am using JWT tokens on the front end for my API based application. I am able to store my token via localstorage, but I also want some application critical data (username and email) stored. Is this considered bad practice or unsafe in any form?

Answer (score 3):

Local Storage data are separate per domain and are stored locally in the user's browser, with that being said, the user or someone with access to the user's browser can easily modify, and look at the data you store there. Obviously users can also see cookies and modify their data.

Rule of thumb is, don't trust the data you store on the client side. I would personally go against storing sensitive information in local storage, or cookies for that matter.